# plugin-transform-spread error while building react app in jenkins

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, babeljs

I get this error when trying to build the react js project in docker. Jenkins is showing build as failed, and this is the error that I am getting-

`[Docker] INFO: [2/4] Fetching packages... [Docker] INFO: [91merror An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/plugin-transform-spread/-/plugin-transform-spread-7.16.7.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".`

I haven't installed any package as plugin-transform-spread. What is babel plugin-transform-spread ?

Comment: Editing the question to include a [mcve] would be very helpful; it's pretty hard to tell what's going on from only an error message.

Comment: What example should I add? I get this error and I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Try removing things in your Dockerfile and package.json until you have enough left that it still fails and nothing else. Then add those two files to your post.

Comment: @DavidMaze and HansKilian Thanks for looking into this. It is fixed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Simply installed the module that jenkins showed as error.
In this case:

`yarn add @babel/plugin-transform-spread --dev`